# Where is ATP used in Phosphorylation?

Tags: plant-physiology, photosynthesis

In the section describing the Calvin Cycle, under the subheading "Reduction",  my textbook states that:

> The steps involve utilisation of 2 molecules of ATP for Phosphorylation...

I could not get where is ATP used in Phosphorylation (ATP synthesis by cells)? Please help me to understand.

Comment: This is a homework question. Even though you got your answer, please put in some effort on your part before asking a question. It is a good practice for everyone.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In biology [phosphorylation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phosphorylation) marks the addition of inorganic phosphate groups to proteins or other organic molecules. The phospho-group usually comes from ATP which is converted into ADP in this process.

In the context of the [Calvin Cycle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Light-independent_reactions#Calvin_Cycle) there are two positions where molecules get phosphorylated. The first is the phosphorylation of 3-phosphogylcerate to 1,3-bisphosphoglyerate, the other is the phosphorylation of Ribulose 5-phosphate to Ribulose 1,5-bisphosphate.

See the image (from [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Light-independent_reactions#Calvin_Cycle)):

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the help! so is it incorrect to say that phosphorylation is synthesis of ATP (since you said that the ATP is converted into ADP in this process)?

Comment: Yes, this is incorrect. Synthesis of ATP is usually referred to as "ATP synthesis".

Comment: @Abdullah, perhaps your confusion about the meaning of 'phosphorylation' in relation to ATP synthesis is because you may have previously learned of a process called 'oxidative phosphorylation' (sometimes abbreviated to OxPhos, or similar) that occurs downstream of the Kreb's Cycle--and is a mechanism cells use to synthesize ATP? Just a thought. The typical and predominant usage in lectures, textbooks, and papers is in Chris's answer that you accepted. The acid anhydride ATP donates its gamma phosphate to some other molecule in a reaction catalyzed by an enzyme.

Comment: Also substrate level phosphorylation…